# How to automate running 1000+ program instances in the Visual Studio debugger

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, debugging, native

On Linux, it is easy to automate running a program under a debugger e.g. scripting gdb via expect to simulator a user loading and running the executable with the specified arguments.

How can running a program a very large number of times with varying arguments under the VS debugger be automated?

The program is a batch mode command line executable, which should be executed several thousand times, with a unique command line in each case.

It is desirable to run multiple parallel debugging sessions.

The direct approach of using the /debugexe argument to devenv requires manual interaction to run e.g. pressing F5 each time.

The approach of creating a solution for the .exe under test and using /RunExit solution seems to require a fixed command line to be used, or a unique solution per invocation.

Comment: Debugging 1000 processes at the same time does not seem as a good idea. Why not just run them all at once, and debug only those that have a problem?

Comment: The goal is to find a non-deterministic crash occurring, it would seem, under load; the manifestation of which is a program crash. The parallel execution is partly to increase machine load, and partly to try each invocation in some reasonable time frame.

Comment: When crash occurs to a specific process you can attach the debugger to it, because process still exists and is debuggable. Then you can see what's going on.

Comment: This program does not appear to do so; it crashes, the process is terminated.